# Modulo Algorithm

Tags: java

I want this function to find the closest value to `n` such that `32 % n == 0` in Java. I'm trying to make this more efficient / functional. Here is what I have tried, but I'm sure there is a better way. I'm using Java 8.

Question: Is there a better way to implement this function that is more efficient?

```
    private static double nearestMod(double n) {
        // Check if n already satisfies the condition
        if (32 % n == 0) {
            return n;
        }
        
        // Check if the solution can't be reasonably obtained
        if (n > 32) {
            return -1;
        }
        
        double increment;
        
        int numsAfterDecimalPoint = String.valueOf(n).split("\\.")[1].length();
        
        if (n % 1 == 0) {
            // If n is a whole number
            increment = 10;
        } else {
            increment = 1d / Math.pow(10, numsAfterDecimalPoint - 1);
        }

        double result = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        
        double multiplier = increment == 10 ? 1 : Math.pow(10, numsAfterDecimalPoint);
        
        for (double i = n - increment * multiplier; i < n + increment * multiplier; i += increment / 10d) {
            double check = 32 / i;
            
            if (Math.abs(Math.round(check) - check) < increment / 10d && Math.abs(i - n) < Math.abs(result - n)) {
                result = i;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Example: `nearestMod(0.26)` should return 0.25

Comment: please clarify what constraints on `n` do we have (like, could it be negative? 0?).

Also if `n > 32` then answer should be 32 it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Handling errors

> ```
>             return -1;
> ```

Consider using an exception in this case rather than a magic value.  Or make a separate method to test for this case, e.g.

```
          public bool isValid(double number) {
              return number <= 32;
          }
```

So you don't have to test the return value for validity.  Instead test validity before calling.

#### Readability

> ```
>         int numsAfterDecimalPoint = String.valueOf(n).split("\\.")[1].length();
> ```

I find this hard to read.  Consider

```
        int numsAfterDecimalPoint = String.valueOf(n).split("[.]")[1].length();
```

Now, rather than having to escape the escape character because it is an escape character in both regular expressions and strings, you have a simple character class.  No need to escape anything.

Or

```
        int numsAfterDecimalPoint = n - Math.floor(n);
```

might be quicker.  No need to convert to a string, just two math operations.

#### Algorithm

But really, I think that you are doing this the hard way.  Consider

```
        double candidate = Math.min(16, Math.pow(2, 1 + Math.getExponent(n))));
        while ( candidate > n) {
            candidate /= 2;
        }

        return (Math.abs(candidate * 2 - n) > Math.abs(candidate - n))
            ? candidate
            : candidate * 2;
```

This saves doing any `Math` operations inside the loop.  It does them before and after, but in the loop it sticks to simple division by 2 and a comparison.

There is no need to get the fractional part of the original number.  Nor to calculate an increment.  We do not need to check (e.g.) .24 or .26, as those aren't going to exactly divide 32.  We have a straightforward calculation that we deliberately do too big (to prevent rounding errors), but only by one value.  So we don't spend much time in our loop.  Then we do another straightforward calculation and comparison to determine which of two values to return (the value smaller than the `candidate` or the next larger candidate, which is `2 * candidate`).

It's possible that we might be able to do this without the loop.  I left it because [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3305400/6660678) suggests that the floating point calculation may err occasionally when trying to get an integer value.

It's possible that there is a problem if `n` is the smallest possible positive value or 0.  If this is something that your calling code might produce, you might want to test it.

In general, I haven't put checks for edge conditions in this code.  Because you don't show how you call this or indicate what the limitations of the inputs/output are.  And I haven't tried to run it.  So be careful.  It may need additional checks to get the same output as you are getting now.

Answer (score 0):

Just some idea.

32 = 2<sup>5</sup>, so *n* = 2k where integer *k* <= 5. k = -2 for 0.26.

That allows integer arithmetic to some degree, diminishing floating point errors.